# Buy and Sell orders of an item in Steam API/JSON

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api, steambot

I'm trying to get buy and sell orders in JSON format like with the price history, but couldn't find any info. Is there a method to do so?

[Buy and Sell orders screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epd3t.png)

I tried:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=ru&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Operation%20Riptide%20Case
```

And:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29/render?start=0&count=1&currency=3&language=english&format=json
```

But they don't display buy and sell orders. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this endpoint: `https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram`

It's the orderbook chart at the bottom of the market pages of popular items, but you can fetch it for any item. Parameters are: `country`, `currency`, `language`, `item_nameid`, and `two_factor`.

Just for example parameters, my `country`, `currency`, and `language` are `US`, `1`(USD), and `english`. `two_factor` can always be set to `0`, and `item_nameid` is what defines which item you're looking up. There's not an easy way to find it, but you can scrape it from here `https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/<appid>/<market_hash_name>` for each item you need. You can find it passed as an argument to the `Market_LoadOrderSpread` function in the page source. Scraping the ids from this page though is rate limited to ~5 requests per minute.

Best of luck!

Edit: As Illia mentions in more detail below, setting the `Referer` header seems to significantly increase the rate at which you can send requests to this endpoint without hitting a rate limit.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently attempting to make regular requests to this endpoint with a 2-minute delay between each request. I'm setting all headers and cookies, but after 20-60 minutes of this activity, I start receiving a 429 error. Maybe you have any updates on this? Have the timeouts really changed so drastically, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Illia I haven't scraped these endpoints in a long time, so I'm sorry to say I don't have any info on updated rate limits. But just trying to use the market normally I get rate limited all the time, so I wouldn't be surprised if the limit was significantly reduced. If you find anything out, I'd love to be able to update this answer with more accurate limits.

Comment: I found out a bug in my code, For using this endpoint it's crucial to use the `Referer` header, and in my code, I was using `Refer` header, so just by adding two letters and setting the `Referer` header to the value `https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/${appId}/${itemName}` I was able to fetch with cooldown for 5-sec hundreds of unique items without catching `429` So sharing this info here, because it took me weeks to find out what was wrong